# how can i Use dropzone without giving action?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, dropzone

I enqueue dropzone js and css and add form and input as define in [dropzone site](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation) but i need the action of form to be empty. and dropzone doesn't work when its empty!
I am new and i dont know how to use it? can anybody help me or at least introduce another js lib that works correctly!

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"   action=""  class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"  >
<input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.2/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", { url: location.href});
</script>
```

It disables the autoDiscover which requires an action and initializes Dropzone with a short custom code.